# Java Mysterious Long Overflow

Tags: java, file, math, io, jvm

I'm trying to get a long 2 GB in bytes to test a file size. The result appears to overflow despite being assigned to a `Long`. This doesn't make any sense to me because in the definition of long, the maximum value is 2^(63)-1 which is much larger than 2 * 1024^3. I have a feeling that it has something to do with a JVM optimization using `Integer`s, but then I'm not sure how to get around this. How should I cast it so it doesn't overflow?

```
long l = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    System.out.println(l);
    System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
long l = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

You are initializing an *int* here, not a `long`!

**When not suffixed, numeric integral literals are `int`s by default**.

You want to write:

```
// NOTE THE L SUFFIX
long l = 2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

It is enough for the *first* literal to be a `long` for the result of an arithmetic operation to be a `long` as well.

Comment: For this calculation, any of the factors can be made a long. In a larger product, I think the first should be made a long.

Answer (score 1):

Append the numbers with L to indicate that they are long values explicitly in the statement:

```
long l = 2L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L;
```

Else, the values in the expression will be treated as integers and then simply assigned to a long.

Comment: You only have to suffix one of them here, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

People have rightly pointed out the problem. Also important here is the evaluation order. In the expression

```
long l = 2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
```

`2 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024` is evaluated first and then the result is assigned to `l`. Since the RHS expression is purely and integer, its evaluated as integer (which you saw as *overflow*) and then assigned to variable on the LHS.

when you change the expression to

`2L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024`, its correctly evaluated as `Long`.